# structured text transformation using vim

Tags: vim

I want to use vim to transform the following block of text from

```
            sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
            sa.Column('title', sa.String(100)),
            sa.Column('isbn', sa.String(20)),
            sa.Column('authors',sa.String(400),nullable=False),
            sa.Column('year',sa.Integer,nullable=False)
```

to

```
  id          = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  title       = Column(String(100))
  isbn        = Column(String(20))
  authors     = Column(String(400),nullable=False)
  year        = Column(Integer,nullable=False)
```

How to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If you could show your attempts and describe what bits you are having difficulty with it would help others help you. As it is, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number of lines you are transforming (e.g. is it really just these couple of lines needing this?), I would consider using a replace text approach if there were more than 30 lines using groupings:

```
:%s/\<sa[.]//g
:%s/\(Column(\)'\([a-z]\+\)',\(.\+\)/\2    =\1 \3/g
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a combination of Blockwise Visual mode (`:h blockwise-visual`) to replace rectangles of characters and Replace mode (`:h R`) to overtype blanks with the content that differs between lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a macro that gets you close:

```
:call setreg('a',"0f'ldw0pa =  \<esc>df.f'df.j")
```

The command will put the recorded macro in your `a` register, so you can call it on the current line by typing `@a`, or on a number lines using `5@a`.

Basically, it does the following steps:

- Jumps to the first `'` on the line and deletes the following word
- Jumps to the start of the line and pastes the word, followed by an `=`
- Deletes from the `=` to the next `.`
- Jumps to the next `'` and deletes until the following `.`

It doesn't remove the trailing commas (you could use a global `:s[ubstitute]` for that) and it doesn't do the aligning.

It is well worth getting used to recording and using macros. They are ideal for this kind of repeatable ad hoc edit. You just need to be careful to record the macro in a repeatable way.